# Is it possible to create autocomplete in Excel (any version) from the list on different sheet?

Tags: vba, excel, autocomplete

I've googled everything I could, scrolled to similar topics here but didn't find straight answer/solution.

I have Sheet A and B.

On sheet A I'm typing the name of a customer and need it to autocomplete from the list that located on sheet B.

Once I have finished typing the customer's name, I need to insert all related information (address, phone #, fax #) about that specific customer to sheet A from the same list on sheet B.

Is this possible in Excel?

Comment: Inserting is easy with `vloopkup`. Autocomplete is much much trickier...

Comment: If you don't have a long list of potential customer's, you can use a [Data Validation List](http://www.databison.com/data-validation-list-in-excel-create-drop-down-list-using-data-validation-in-excel/) for the AutoComplete part (although it would be a pick list.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman, I think Data Validation list don't has AutoComplete if the list is not at the same column , the list in this question is in other sheet, Please can you post an answer explain it , I really need this. I upvoted this question when I saw it because it is very important for me.

Comment: @Fadi - see my note at the end of the post (although it would be a pick list). AFAIK, data validation will not autocomplete, if not in the same column, as you noted.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman, thank you for comment. and I'm sorry because always my english  don't help me :).

Answer (score -1):

Inside code of sheetA you put this...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'You want to insert the data in column B
    Dim i
    Dim r

    r = Target.Row
    i = Target.Column
    If i = 2 Then
        'you want to to put the telephone in column C
        Range(Cells(r, i + 1), Cells(r, i + 1)).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Target.Value, Range([...]), [integer], False|True)

        'you want to to put the address in column d
        Range(Cells(r, i + 2), Cells(r, i + 2)).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Target.Value, Range([...]), [integer], False|True)
    End If
End Sub
```

Or May be you want to see the formula inside the cells

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'You want to insert the data in column B
    Dim i
    Dim r

    r = Target.Row
    i = Target.Column
    If i = 2 Then
        'you want to to put the telephone in column C
        Range(Cells(r, i + 1), Cells(r, i + 1)).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],SheetB!R1C6:R13C10,2,FALSE)"

        'you want to to put the address in column d
        Range(Cells(r, i + 2), Cells(r, i + 2)).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-2],SheetB!R1C6:R13C10,3,FALSE)"
    End If
End Sub
```

This way everytime you insert some data in any cell of colunm B, in column C on the same row, you will get the data as in the column D on the same row as column B.

**Edit #1**
Just in case: In the first example, `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Target.Value, Range([...]), [integer], False|True)` in real code would be like this

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Target.Value, Range("F1:J13"), 2, False)
Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Target.Value, Range(Cells(1,6),cells(13,10)), 2, False)
```

This two lines are the same.

**Edit**

Change the function `SelectionChange` for `Worksheet_Change`

Comment: why would have a `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event perform a vlookup, when you can just write the vlookup right into the sheet as a formula?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman to avoid the human error, and not to see the formula. Anyway, as you can see in the second part of the example, the functions add the formula. And if you have a excel sheet and you do not know how many lines you will need this is usefull, adding just the formulas per row that you need, not more not less, and this is a advantage when you need to care about, the size of the file.

Comment: Please if this answer help you let me know.